# ajaxcontrol tool kit htmleditor shows blank for image

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to use the ajaxcontrol tool kit htmleditor. below is the code that i found online

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInstruction" runat="server" Wrap="true" Width="600px" Height="300px" TextMode="MultiLine"  />
                    <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="MyHtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtInstruction" DisplaySourceTab="true" 
                        OnImageUploadComplete="MyHtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete" >
                        <Toolbar>
                            <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
                            <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
                            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
                            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
                            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
                            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
                            <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
                            <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
                            <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
                            <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
                            <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
                            <ajaxToolkit:SelectAll />
                            <ajaxToolkit:UnSelect />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Delete />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
                            <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
                            <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
                            <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
                            <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
                            <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
                            <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
                            <ajaxToolkit:HorizontalSeparator />
                            <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />
                        </Toolbar>
                    </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

here is the bode behind

```
protected void MyHtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
            // Generate file path
            string filePath = "~/tmpImages/" + e.FileName;

            // Save uploaded file to the file system
            var ajaxFileUpload = (AjaxFileUpload)sender;
            ajaxFileUpload.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

            // Update client with saved image path
            e.PostedUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(filePath);

    }
```

the error message that i am keep getting is "Unable to cast object of type 'UploadRequestProcessor' to type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload'." everytime i click on upload button.

I'm getting the example from [AJAX Html Editor Extender upload image appearing blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674893/ajax-html-editor-extender-upload-image-appearing-blank/23842239) so i'm not sure what i'm missing. if i take this line of code 
    var ajaxFileUpload = (AjaxFileUpload)sender;
out, it will let me save the upload image into the folder but the image would be blank in the editor. Any help is really appreciated. thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is [fixed](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/327) and queued to the next release.

You can download the latest build [from here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/dxrobot/ajaxcontroltoolkit/build/artifacts) with the fix.

Comment: so it's not fixed right now? :( do you know when the next release is?

Comment: It's released yet, but you can download the latest build [from here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/dxrobot/ajaxcontroltoolkit/build/artifacts) with the fix.